# PHP imap_open with NTLM hash

Tags: php, exchange-server, ntlm, php-imap

i have NTLM hash of MS exchange server. I can login with credentials using username and password and get mails information with `php_imap()` functions, I didn't found any information how to login to mailbox using NTLM hash. It's possible? PHP documentation provides only information how to disable NTLM authentication. 
All I found is this request: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34609

Comment: As you didn´t specify if its in generall working (e.g. via an eMail client) just a side note here (more info's [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997188(v=exchg.141).aspx)): 1.)Make sure NTLM is enabled 2.) Integrated Windows authentication (NTLM) is only supported for POP3 or IMAP4 connections with Exchange SP1 and above.

Comment: Connection works with: `$mailbox = new PhpImap\Mailbox('{server_ip:143/novalidate-cert/imap4}', 'username', 'password', $save_folder)` , but now customer provided NTLM hash and I can't connect.

Comment: of possible interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652234/pass-through-ntlm-authentication-in-a-web-app-on-an-imap-mail-server

Comment: It' not only about authentication, I need to get access to mailbox and get mails content. I'm using `barbushin/php-imap` lib for now to do that with username and password and still can find way to it with hash.